# Magento 2 programatically delete cart of customer in magento 2

Tags: magento2, cart, customer

How can i programatically delete cart of  customer in magento 2.

Comment: are you looking to do this via PHP script or direct SQL query

Comment: actually i need to create a api ..so i need to delete it via PHP

Comment: This should give you the answer you need https://webkul.com/blog/how-to-delete-items-from-cart-in-magento2/

Answer (score 2):

Add to your class

```
protected $_session;

public function __construct(
...
\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $session
..
){
$this->_session = $session;
}
```

And then paste this code where you want

```
$quote = $this->_session->getQuote();
$quote->removeAllItems();
```